# Equivalent of SQL "greatest" function for Apache Derby?

Tags: sql, derby, sql-function

I'm looking for a way to emulate "greatest", as implemented in various databases such as H2DB (http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#greatest) and Oracle, within Apache Derby. Pointers appreciated.

EDIT: I only need for two values, so that I can conditionally update a column based on the previous value.

Comment: Writing your own function is probably the best way to do it. For just two or three values, you can get away using a `CASE` statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - that pointed me into the right direction: "set X = CASE WHEN X > FOO THEN X ELSE FOO END" seems to do just what I need; do you want to transform your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a subquery with `union all` and select `max` from it? 
using oracle syntax...

```
  SELECT MAX(p) AS "greatest"
  FROM (SELECT '1' AS p
          FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '2'
          FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '3' FROM dual)
```